# Executing custom query in JPA Repository (Spring Data Jpa)

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Using Spring Boot Application.
I have class UserService in which I am creating a dynamic query with multiple or conditions depending on request parameters:

```
Select care_adl_id, adl_text,  hr from (select care_adl_id, adl_text, extract(hour from actual_hour)hr from adl_events) as evt where  
care_adl_id = 1 and hr > 6 and hr < 15 
 or care_adl_id = 2 and hr > 6 and hr < 15  
 or care_adl_id = 3 and hr > 15 and hr < 23
```

I have UserRepository interface, I need to execute this query. Till now I have used JPA functions like findById etc. or @Query("Select id from Events").

How to pass this query from service class to repository and execute it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [spring-dynamic-jpa](https://github.com/joutvhu/spring-dynamic-jpa) library. You just need to write a query template, it will help you to change the query based on parameters.